# I need to transport a javascript object via query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cross-domain

I have a javascript object that I need to be able to pass to a web service via query string.

Say for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var test = new Object();
test.date = new Date();
test.str = "hello world!";
test.list = new Array();
test.list.push('a');
test.list.push('b');
test.list.push('c');
</script>
```

Is there a way that I can serialize that object as JSON and then compress/encode it in some way that can be passed into a url's query string?

like:

```
var destination = 'http://mywebservice?'+encode(serialize(test));
$.get(destination, function(e)) { ... }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most modern browsers have a native JSON object that you can use: `JSON.stringify(myObject);` (to support almost all browsers, use json2.js from http://www.json.org)

Comment: Note that IE7 doesn't have the JSON object: http://caniuse.com/json - so for a while, you should use json2.js

Comment: If you the option, you should consider delivering your payload via POST rather than GET.

Comment: If you use jQuery, then you should pass the data as second parameter to the function. jQuery will take care of the proper encoding of the data. I agree with using JSON and if possible, you should use POST.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want Douglas Crockford's json2.js: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

```
var test = new Object();
test.date = new Date();
test.str = "hello world!";

var dest = 'http://mywebservice?'+encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify(test) );
```

*(oh, and don't use escape(), it's deprecated. Always use encodeURIComponent() instead)*

But why not use a (session) cookie instead? Using the URI to pass data can be a major problem for SEO, for bookmarks, for links, etc.

Comment: Before it comes to using cookies as an alternative, the more proper way to pass a large payload would be to use a POST or a PUT. Cookies should be used to store state and not for data transport.

Comment: i can't use post or put due to cross-domain policy.

Answer (score 6):

You should remember that query string has maximum length (wiki said that it is 2083 chars), so you have to be carefully with putting there too large objects.

Answer (score -1):

Use the standard JSON `stringify()` method:

`var destination = encodeURI('http://mywebservice?obj='+ JSON.stringify(test));`

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need jQuery post function:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

It does perform a post of the data to the server. In my opinion a POST is better suited to send objects but I ignore the limitations you might have on the server.